# String validation with variable length?

Tags: validation

I am using SharePoint 2013 and I am trying to validate a field that has a variable starting length but a certain format.

The format I am using is XXxx-123456. Where 123456 is any 6 digits and XXxx is any letter this field can vary from 2 letters to 4.

I am using the below code if it is in the format of XX-123456. I am just not sure on how to allow the first part to be between 2 and 4 characters but always a letter.

```
(LEN([Issue Number])=9)+
(CODE(MID([Issue Number],1,1))>64)+(CODE(MID([Issue Number],1,1))<90)+
(CODE(MID([Issue Number],2,1))>64)+(CODE(MID([Issue Number],2,1))<90)+
(MID([Issue Number],3,1)="-")+
(CODE(MID([Issue Number],4,1))>47)+(CODE(MID([Issue Number],4,1))<58)+
(CODE(MID([Issue Number],5,1))>47)+(CODE(MID([Issue Number],5,1))<58)+
(CODE(MID([Issue Number],6,1))>47)+(CODE(MID([Issue Number],6,1))<58)+
(CODE(MID([Issue Number],7,1))>47)+(CODE(MID([Issue Number],7,1))<58)+
(CODE(MID([Issue Number],8,1))>47)+(CODE(MID([Issue Number],8,1))<58)+
(CODE(MID([Issue Number],9,1))>47)+(CODE(MID([Issue Number],9,1))<58)=18
```

Comment: have you considered using regex instead?

Comment: I have I just don't know how to implement that in sharepoint

Comment: is this a field validation formula?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this http://sharepointregex.codeplex.com/
It's a regex field, or you could implement one by yourself:

It's a bit complicated but you could define a Regex Field like this:
1. Map the XML Folder in your Solution
2. Create new XML with name: fldtypes_RegularExpressionField.xml
3. Insert this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FieldTypes>
  <FieldType>
    <Field Name="TypeName">RegularExpressionField</Field>
    <Field Name="ParentType">Text</Field>
    <Field Name="TypeDisplayName">Regular Expression Text</Field>
    <Field Name="TypeShortDescription">Regular Expression Validated Text</Field>
    <Field Name="UserCreatable">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="ShowInListCreate">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="ShowInEditForm">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="ShowInNewForm">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="ShowInDisplayForm">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="ShowInDocumentLibraryCreate">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="ShowInColumnTemplateCreate">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="FieldTypeClass">Shop.FieldTypes.RegularExpressionFieldType, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Field>
    <PropertySchema>
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="regularExpression" DisplayName="Regular expression:" Type="Text" Required="TRUE" DisplaySize="30" />
        <Field Name="errorMessage" DisplayName="Error message:" Type="Text" Required="TRUE" DisplaySize="30" />
      </Fields>
    </PropertySchema>
  </FieldType>
</FieldTypes>
```

4. Create a Class RegularExpressionFieldType

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace Shop.FieldTypes
{
    public class RegularExpressionFieldType : SPFieldText
    {
        public RegularExpressionFieldType(SPFieldCollection fields, string fieldName) : base(fields, fieldName)
        {
        }

        public RegularExpressionFieldType(SPFieldCollection fields, string typeName, string displayName) : base(fields, typeName, displayName)
        {
        }

        public override string GetValidatedString(object value)
        {
            var stringValue = value.ToString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
            {
                var pattern = ((XmlNode[]) GetCustomProperty("regularExpression"))[0].Value;
                if (!Regex.IsMatch(stringValue, pattern))
                {
                    throw new SPFieldValidationException(((XmlNode[])GetCustomProperty("errorMessage"))[0].Value);
                }
            }
            return base.GetValidatedString(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you deploy it and after that, you can add a Column of this type and use a regex to validate the field. Tell me if it worked for you, it's been a while since I used it.

Answer (score -1):

C# version (server side validation):

```
var parts = field_val.Split('-');
int secondPart;
bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(parts[1], out secondPart);

if ((4 >= parts[0].Length && parts[0].Length >= 2) && (isNumeric && parts[0].Length == 6))
{
    // valid
}
else
{
    // invalid
}
```

you may want this to be a client side validation, in which case you'll need a javascript version, but functionally, it  is more or less the same thing.

Comment: But to be honest if he is using SharePoint OOB List Forms, how will this work.. you didn't mention any Event Receiver or something..

Comment: good point, will update to mention that. Going to have to do after work though.